# Why is jbox('Image' no longer working as documented?

Tags: jbox

I have upgraded my version of jBox from "*old, 2016ish*" to 0.4.9 today and checked if my code was still working - and noticed that `Image` seems to behave differently now. Investigating this in more detail I have build this [fiddle](https://codepen.io/MBaas/pen/BJqrEe) which uses essentially the same code as Stephan's [sample](https://stephanwagner.me/jBox/get_started#images) (plus a bit of harmless CSS) and still fails - so if even Stephan's example does not work I believe there must a bug in jBox, not in my code...

**Fiddle**: [here](https://codepen.io/MBaas/pen/BJqrEe)

**HTML**:

```
<a href="https://stephanwagner.me/img/jBox/demo-img/CIMG4778_large.jpg" title="My title 1" data-jbox-image="gallery1" class="demo-img1"><img src="https://stephanwagner.me/img/jBox/demo-img/CIMG4778_small.jpg" alt=""></a>
<a href="https://stephanwagner.me/img/jBox/demo-img/CIMG4547_large.jpg" title="My title 2" data-jbox-image="gallery1" class="demo-img1"><img src="https://stephanwagner.me/img/jBox/demo-img/CIMG4547_small.jpg" alt=""></a>
```

**JS**:

```
new jBox('Image');
```

BTW, I have also experimented with `$(function(){new jBox("Image");});`but that did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I had not loaded `plugins/Image/jBox.Image.css` and `plugins/Image/jBox.Image.js`

Answer (score 1):

Remember to initialise jBox when your DOM is ready: https://jsfiddle.net/StephanWagner/q8cv1Lqg/

`$(document).ready(function() {
    new jBox("Image");
});`

Comment: Thanks - but I actually did not bother to load the plugin before using it! ;-(